# Error when mapping graphQL Object in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to map an object from a graphQL query in React. I'm getting an error when I try to do it:

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Here's the component with the mapping:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { COORDS } from "./coords"
import { useMileDispatch, useMileState } from './MileContext';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import Location from "./location";


    const CustomTrip = () => {
      const {locationOne, locationTwo} = useMileState()
      const dispatch = useMileDispatch()



      async function fetchDistance()
            {

                const res = await fetch("https://api.mapbox.com/directions-matrix/v1/mapbox/driving/" + locationOne + ";" + locationTwo + "?sources=1&annotations=distance&access_token=[token obscured]")
                console.log(res);
                const mapBoxObject = await res.json();
                console.log(mapBoxObject);
                const meters = mapBoxObject.distances[0];
                console.log(meters);
                const miles = (parseInt(meters) *  0.00062137119);
                const roundtrip = 2 * miles;

                console.log(miles.toFixed(2));

                dispatch({type: 'totalMilesUpdate', payload: roundtrip.toFixed(2)})

            }

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchDistance()
        }, [locationOne, locationTwo]);

      const LOCATIONS = gql`
        {
          locations {
            id
            slug
            gps
          }
        }
        `;
      const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LOCATIONS);


      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

      return (
        <div>
          <h3>Customize your trip</h3>
            Mileage will be calculated as a round trip.
            <br/>
            Select your starting point

            <select value={locationOne} onChange={(event) => dispatch({type: 'locationOneChange', payload: event.target.value})}>
            {
                Object.entries(data.LOCATIONS).map(([slug, gps]) => (
                <Location />
            ))}
            </select>

            Select your destination
            <select value={locationTwo} onChange={(event) => dispatch({type: 'locationTwoChange', payload: event.target.value})}>
            {
                Object.entries(data.LOCATIONS).map(([slug, gps]) => (
                <Location />
            ))}
            </select>
        </div>
      )
    };

export default CustomTrip;
```

I also have a component with the selects here:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { COORDS } from "./coords"
import { useMileDispatch, useMileState } from './MileContext';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const Location = () => {

  const LOCATIONS = gql`
        {
          locations {
            id
            slug
            gps
          }
        }
      `;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LOCATIONS);
  if (loading) return <option value="-73.778716,42.740913">ALB</option>;
  if (error) return <option value="-73.778716,42.740913">ALB</option>;


    return data.locations.map(({ slug, gps }) => (

            <option key={slug} value={gps}>
            {slug}
            </option>

    ))





};

export default Location;
```

What am I doing wrong is there some syntax missing? The idea is that I will be able to choose locations from one drop down list for the starting point and the second dropdown list will have the destination. The mapbox api will then calculate the driving distance in meters and I will then convert it to miles to pass that value to state where computations will be done on it to determine the costs for the trip in question. This works fine when I use a plain object but I wanted to improve the app overall by integrating an api that will allow users the ability to add/remove/edit locations and then be able to perforrm the same computations on those locations.

***edit***
thanks to @xadm I changed the syntax to Object.entries(data.locations).map in the first component and that works great except for one thing... Now I'm getting all the entries duplicated like 4 times or so. Any idea why that is?

Comment: check for Object.entries(data.LOCATIONS) if data.LOCATIONS is an object.It may be coming as null

Comment: just use `data.locations.map` (as in second snippet) - not `data.LOCATIONS` ... js is case sensitive

Comment: @xadm that was a great suggestion! I changed that part to: Object.entries(data.locations).map(([slug, gps]) => (

Comment: Now my object entries are repeated about 4 times. Any clue why that would be?

Comment: you don't need `Object.entries()` (as in 2nd snippet) ... you should pass values as props into `<Location/>` components ... you should also use `key` property on all looped items/components.